# Format Excel Cells based on their values

Tags: vb.net, excel

How do I format a cell in Excel based on its value using VB.Net.

I have a code that calculates the value in VB.Net and export the results to an Excel sheet.

I want to format each cell that starts with the word "Total" as I have many totals like Total 1, Total, 2, etc..., and the cell next to it to the right where the actual value of the total is.
I tried creating a new sub to format the cells and call it, and tried placing the code in the same function at the end where the totals are being calculated. It did not work as I am getting different error messages like not enough memory, or you need to create an instance, etc...

```
With xlWorkSheet.Range("A1:IV65536").Value = "Total*"
        .size = "20"
End With
```

Comment: You're getting confused. Study up the With statement, you cant say `With` and assign value to it, that needs to be done on the next line. To fix it simply put a line feed before the `.Value =`

Answer (score 0):

That code is, to be overly polite, not correct.

```
xlWorkSheet.Range("A1:IV65536").Font.Size = 20
```

would change the font-size but you need to incorporate an If-statement to check the `Value`.

(You should also include the full erorr-message in your post.)

Comment: How do I check the value of a cell for the whole sheet?